# How to select specific month out of certain data

Tags: python, average

I want to calculate the monthly average over years, for example, I have monthly data from 2010 to 2020, and now I want to calculate the average for January over this 10 years period. How can I select data for each January throughout these 10 years?

Comment: do you keep date in single column or as separated columns for year, month, day?

Answer (score 3):

If you import pandas you can use a DataFrame and `groupby` with `mean` of the months:

```
import pandas as pd

#import data here into dataframe as df

df.groupby(['Month']).mean()
```

EDIT:

If your data looks something like this:

```
year,month,data
2010,january,5
2011,january,10
2010,february,15
2011,february,20
```

you can import the csv and then 'groupby' month and data:

```
import pandas as pd

#load data
df = pd.read_csv('csv file')

#will show data grouped by months
data_by_month = df.groupby('month').data.mean().reset_index()

#you can filter by the months
data_by_month[data_by_month.month == 'january']
```